# Converting xslt / Jar as EXE file

Tags: java, xslt, exe

I have done some xsl coding and this xsl code is called through a jar and it generates the output xml in the output folder that I have specified.
Instead of calling a jar to run the xslt files, I would like to change it as exe file, for security reasons.
Is there any option for converting my xslt codes along with this jar to an exe file, so that finally I can call this exe file alone for running my code? Please help.

Comment: Yes.  Good keywords to search for here is java and EXE: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+exe

Comment: i have used http://www.jar2exe.com/, a simple google query will give you loads of suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "for security reasons"?  What makes calling the JAR through your own custom `.exe` any more or less secure than using the JRE's own `java.exe`?

Comment: Or are you looking for a solution that doesn't require Java to be installed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to the [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). It's provide the conversion of the jar files into the exe files.